# JSON encoded PHP not an object?

Tags: php, json, tabulator

I'm trying to send data via Ajax, and I'm getting the following error:

> Data Loading Warning - Invalid row data detected and ignored, expecting 
>       object but received: {PK:'2', ID:'3'} (anonymous) @ tabulator.min.js:2

I created a PHP string which I put into an array and used `json_encode()`. It recognizes the array, but not the object in it. Is there anything more I have to do for it to be read as a JSON object?

I created the string as follows:

```
$datarray = [];
while ($fetch = $stmt->fetch()){
        $data = "{ PK:'2', id:'23' }";
        array_push($datarray, $data);
}
echo json_encode($datarray);
```

This was in an ajax requested page. The string was originally populated by the query, but I simplified it down and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Please extract a [mcve], so this situation can be reproduced.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I added the script I am using to generate the ajax response. I don't have the exact script that is receiving it as it is from the tabulator library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the issue. To use `json_encode` it has to be in PHP format. i.e. `$key=>$value` and not it JSON format `{ key:'value'}`. Otherwise, the encoding doesn't work properly. When I switched it to that format it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Need to parse json string before using in js: `JSON.parse(data)`

Answer (score 0):

You must try this

```
$datarray = [];
while ($fetch = $stmt->fetch()){
        $data = "{ PK:'2', id:'23' }";
        $data = array(
          "PK"=>2,
           "id"=>23
        );
        array_push($datarray, $data);
}
echo json_encode($datarray);
```